# Max and Mean command produce the same result

Tags: equation-solving, pure-function

I tried to find a point that is nearest to two other points, using both "Max" and "Mean". I wonder why both produce the same value. I tried changing the input, but the results by using "Max" and "Mean" are still the same. Is it because the "Minimize" enforces the results to be the same?

[image]

Comment: Your RA is only using 2 pieces of data. Try using more numbers: RA={PB,PC,PA}

Comment: _Is it because the "Minimize" enforces the results to be the same?_ No. Just evaluate `f[x,y]` for several values of `x` and `y`.